# Align unnumbered and numbered chapters

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, templates

I'm using the ERDC template and when I make an unnumbered chapter (\chapter*) it doesn't align with the numbered chapter on the next page. Cant identify any custom format in the ERDC cls code.

erdc package:

https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/erdc

[image: PDF preview]

Comment: The sharelatex link:

https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/re%C2%ADports-by-us-army-corps-of-engi%C2%ADneers

Comment: you mean don't align horizontally because they align vertically.

Comment: Yes I mean the horizontal alignment

Comment: can you explain how do you want it to be, I find that it will break design.

Comment: I want the text to start at the same horizontal position with a numbered chapter as with an unnumbered chapter. So the only difference is that the number isnt there. No other format change.

Comment: Ok I will try to answer later (this night)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{erdc}
\usepackage{lipsum,url}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
 % ajust horizontal alignement
\let\@makeschapterhead\@makechapterhead   
%this for table of contents 
\patchcmd{\specialchapter}{\@makeschapterhead{#1}}{% 
\@makeschapterhead{\makebox[35\p@]{\mbox{}\hfill}#1}}{}{}
 %for preface ...(\frontmatter)
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\@makechapterhead{#2}}{% 
\@makechapterhead{\makebox[35\p@]{\mbox{}\hfill}#2}}{}{}
% for numbered appendix
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\@makechapterhead{\@chapapp\space\thechapter: #2}}{%
\@makechapterhead{\makebox[35\p@]{\mbox{}\hfill}\@chapapp\space\thechapter: #2}}{}{}
% for unnumbered chapters
\patchcmd{\@schapter}{\@makeschapterhead{#1}}{%
\@makeschapterhead{\makebox[35\p@]{\mbox{}\hfill}#1}}{}{}
 % for unnumbered appendix
\patchcmd{\@schapter}{\@makeschapterhead{\@chapapp: #1}}{%
\@makeschapterhead{\makebox[35\p@]{\mbox{}\hfill}\@chapapp: #1}}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
```